# Package 'ruby1.8-dev' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, ruby

How can I solve this error?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install libgemplugin-ruby
```

Currently I am getting this error:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ruby1.8-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'ruby1.8-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to do anything with sources.list

first do `apt-cache search ruby1.8`
it will list all the packages. note the name of desired package you want to install and then just do sudo install with that package name.